# How to check whether session is null or not in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How to check whether session is null or not in javascript?It is right way?

```
if ('<%=Session["Time"] == null%>')
{
    alert('null session');
}
```

Comment: This is not JavaScript,but...

Comment: Is it not Javascript being used in combination with a server side response.write of a value to be evaluated client side?

Comment: Sorry, should have said "If one makes the assumption that this is code located in an aspx page, then is it not javascript....."

Comment: @Steve,I was in wrong impression.Condition is true or false/If false means not null.I should update my code like this

Comment: var flag = '<%=Session["Time"] == null%>';
       if (flag.toLowerCase() == 'true')
       {alert('session is null')
       }
       else
       {
           // some code.
       }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that will test every 500 milliseconds if the user session has expired.

```
 function CheckSession() {
            var session = '<%=Session["username"] != null%>';
            if (session == false) {
                alert("Your Session has expired");
                window.location = "login.aspx";
            }
        }

setInterval(CheckSession(),500);
```

Comment: This will just result in var session being equal to either 'True' or 'False' which will not equal true or false.

Answer (score 2):

You must try the following code:

```
 var IsNull= '@Session["CallType"]'!= null;
```

Output:
  **IsNull** value will be true or false.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code to check the Session.

```
public string TransactionID
{
   get { 
        var data = ((Hashtable)(Session["SessionData"])); 
        if (data != null)
           return data["TransactionID "];
        else
           return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: This isn't Javascript, and doesn't check if the session is null. One would still need to check if the value returned was null.

Answer (score 0):

if ('<%=Session["Time"] == null%>') will either evaluate to if ('True') or if ('False') which is equal to true in javascript: You may try as below:

```
if (<%=((Session["Time"] == null) ? 1 : 0))%>)
{
    alert('null session');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
var isNullSession = <%=(Session["time"]==null).ToString().ToLower()%>;
if (isNullSession) {
    alert('A null session variable I be');
}
```

This wouldn't mean the "Session" was null, just the session variable "time".

Steve

Answer (score 0):

Here is the procedure to check whether session is null or not in Javascript. we have to do something like this.

```
var sessionValue = '<%=Session["Time"] != null%>';
```

So here is the point, if Session["Time"] is not null then it will return 
**'True'** which is a string in this case. so then we can do our further 
processing in this manner.

```
if (sessionValue == 'True')
{
    alert('session is not null');
}
else
{
   alert('session is null');
}
```